# Constructor nominated by using declaration

Tags: c++, class, constructor, using, language-lawyer

I'm trying to declare a member name which is constructor of base class as the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class A{ };

class B: public A
{
    using A::A; //error: ‘A::A’ names constructor
};

int main()
{
}
```

Where is it specified that constructor cannot be accepted by using declaration? I'm looking for a corresponding quote from the Standard.

Comment: Inheriting constructors is a C++11 feature.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/hHi2Iu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where is it specified that constructor cannot be accepted by using declaration?

Nowhere, because it can. See **12 Special Member Functions**:

> **12.9 Inheriting constructors [class.inhctor]**
>
> A using-declaration (7.3.3) that names a constructor implicitly declares a set of
>   inheriting constructors. The candidate set of inherited constructors from the class X named in the using-declaration consists of actual constructors and notional constructors that result from the transformation of defaulted parameters as follows:
>
> — all non-template constructors of X, and
>
> — for each non-template constructor of X that has at least one parameter with a default argument, the set of constructors that results from omitting any ellipsis parameter specification and successively omitting parameters with a default argument from the end of the parameter-type-list, and
>
> — all constructor templates of X, and
>
> — for each constructor template of X that has at least one parameter with a default argument, the set of constructor templates that results from omitting any ellipsis parameter specification and successively omitting parameters with a default argument from the end of the parameter-type-list.
>
> ....

Here's an example:

```
struct A
{ 
  explicit A(int) {}    
};

struct B: A
{
    using A::A;
};

int main()
{
    B b{42};
}
```

Comment: But if I'm compiling it with g++ -c test.cpp -std=c++11 I have the same error. Can you explain that?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Perhaps your compiler does not have full C++11 language support. This was one of the last features to get implemented in GCC.